# WPF Binding with StringFormat-ting for float values

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I know there are a lot of answers to this, but in my case it doesn't work, looks like it's something specific I'm struggling with.

I have this piece of code on my XAML side, but for some reason these text blocks show the raw float values rounded up to 2 decimal points, whereas, based on the string formatting it supposed to show up to 4 decimal points if there are. In my case I was expecting to show my Y value to show in tooltip 12.1864, but it shows 12.19. How can I make it format the way I want?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="X: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Y: "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding YValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

[image]

Comment: Two questions: (1) can you include the definitions for the properties you're binding to? (2) Are you by chance pulling those values from a database?

Comment: public string FormattedXValue {get;}
I guess it doesn't do any implicit conversion before formatting once again. I think I got the root cause.

Since these properties are from a third party lib then I'll probably do value conversion to bring it to float before formatting with my custom pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint by @KeithStein I figured it out. The issue was the type of the bound properties, which in my case where from a third party lib and was string. I could have implement a value converter, but I was lucky the third lib also has an option of the same float values not in string but in raw float type. So binding to those and keeping the same XAML code, worked well for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code & it works fine as expected with 4 decimal points,
[image]

Please find code below

```
    public string XValue { get; set; }

    public string YValue { get; set; }

    private void setXYValue()
    {
        XValue = "19.45678";
        YValue = "20.12345";

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(XValue));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YValue));
    }



      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="X: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}"/>  
        </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Y: "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding YValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: `XValue` and `YValue` are numeric values, not strings.

Comment: @Peregrine Even with numeric values it work fine,

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine for me

```
<Window
    x:Class="BindingFormatTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingFormatTest"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="X: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding XValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Y: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding YValue, StringFormat={}{0:#.####}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public class MainViewModel
{
    public double XValue { get; } = 12.345678;

    public double YValue { get; } = 23.456789;
}
```

[image]

Try using a tool such as WPFSnoop to check that the data context and the values are really what you expected.